# Locate value in the end of a string

Tags: c#, regex

If the bracket and the data inside of the bracket is in the end of a string value, then it should be true.

The problem that I'm facing is that I find solution. I tried but I failed.

The correct regex code is

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

---

```
fff (335g) ff
false

aa(f344f)
true

aa (aa)
true
```

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't checking the end of the string. Try \(([^)]*)\)$

Comment: @crunchy : Missing the backslashes. The way you wrote it parentheses won't be matched.

Comment: @BHustus well spotted sir!

Comment: @HelloWorld: Try [`@"[^\s(]*\([^()]*\)\z"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5cs\(%5d*%5c\(%5b%5e\(\)%5d*%5c\)%5cz&i=aa\(f344f\)).

Comment: Than you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
/\(.*\)$/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS6pA9/1)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
\(([^)]*)\)$
```

The only thing you need to add is the end-of-string anchor, the dollar sign. When hit, this effectively matches the end of the string, saying 'this is only a match if nothing is beyond this point'.

(Note: In multiline mode, the `$` will also match the end of the line)

Comment: But what about **aa(f344f)**.It is not matching by using your regex.

Comment: Thank you for your help!